# How could I generate a customized javadoc of a class, package ... to pdf in eclipse or something in maven?

Tags: javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, doclet

How could I generate a customized javadoc of a class, package ... to pdf in eclipse or something in maven?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <id>PDF</id>
            <reports>
                 <report>javadoc</report>
            </reports>
            <configuration>
                <name>PDF</name>
                <description>This is my Documentation on PDF.</description>
                <destDir>pdf</destDir>
                <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
                <docletPath>${basedir}\..\..\tools\pdfdoclet-1.0.3-all.jar</docletPath>                         
                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                <additionalparam>
                    -pdf javadoc.pdf
                </additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

I tried many way also use the maven-pdf-plugin and pdfdoclet... but unsuccessfully or I did with a wrong way? Could u give me some advises? Or some guides, some tutorial?...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've submitted a fix for your formatting, but please make a better effort in the future to properly format your code.